# Strange behaviour in C program, variable corruption after allocating memory

Tags: c, string, malloc

I have typdef of string in my C program, it looks like that:

```
#define WRD_LEN 100
typedef char cstring[WRD_LEN];
```

then at some point I declare dynamic array of this type:

```
int pcount = 1;
cstring *options = malloc(sizeof(cstring*)*pcount);
```

I add new strings to this array with use of realloc:

```
options = realloc(options, sizeof(cstring*)*pcount);
strcpy(options[pcount-1], //some string//);
pcount++;
```

and then show all entries to user, user choses one of them and that one is passed to another function:

```
highestof(mode, l, options[btn]);
```

mode is an integer, l is struct but those are irrelevant now. btn is number (int) of entry chosed by user.
Up to this point everything works just fine, problem shows up inside **highestof** function:

```
void highestof(const int mode, List l, const cstring cat) {
List *p = malloc(sizeof(List*));
```

here is definition of **List**:

```
struct W {
    //some data
    struct W *next;
};
struct List {
    struct W *first;
};
```

So if **highestof** function is called with **options[1]**, **cat** variable will get corrupted (it will became a set of few random symbols, like "#^?" or "^K^?") right after **malloc** is called i.e. before creating dynamic array of List I can use **cat** as much as I want, but after calling **malloc** it gets corrupted. Most strange thing about this is that it happens only if variable passed down to this function was in **options** array under index of 1 (**options[btn]** where **btn** = 1) For any other value of **btn** it works no problem.

I found a workaround for this, I can create a string (char s[100]) before calling **malloc**, copy **cat** value into it and use that variable instead, but it's really not resolving initial problem and it really bothers me.

Comment: it should be `sizeof(cstring)`, not `sizeof(cstring*)`. The `sizeof` argument always should have one less `*` than the pointer you're assigning to.

Comment: @Barmar Disagree with [sizeof argument always should have one less * than the pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54262748/strange-behaviour-in-c-program-variable-corruption-after-allocating-memory/54262966#comment95349665_54262748).  I recommend  the `*` with the pointer, rather than the pointer type moved  as in `sizeof *options * pcount`

Comment: @chux That's another way to do it. But if you're doing it with the type, it should have one less `*`.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(cstring*)*pcount` is too small.  The size calculation is amiss.

---

Avoid allocation errors.  Use this idiom for code that is easier to write correctly, review and maintain.
Notice no *type* is used.

```
pointer = malloc(sizeof *pointer * n);
```

Then code becomes:

```
// options = malloc(sizeof(cstring*)*pcount);
options = malloc(sizeof *options * pcount);`
```

Answer (score 1):

`cstring*` is just a pointer, usually four or eight bytes. `sizeof (cstring*)` is therefore a small number, usually four or eight.

You are not allocating enough memory for the data, just enough memory to hold pointers to the data.

Comment: Nitpick: "*`cstring*` is just a pointer*" not quiet right. `cstring*` is a pointer *type*.